# Way to express a number in its most compact sum of powers

Tags: number-theory, numerical-methods, power-series, computer-science, exponentiation

Given a non-negative number **n**, what is the best approach to find the most compact representation for **n** in terms of sums of powers, such that the bases and the exponents can't surpass a given value (for instance, $2^{32}$)?
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \alpha_i(\beta_i)^{\gamma_i}$$

The gammas are the exponents and are limited in range (they are non-negative integers and can't surpass $2^{32}$). The betas are the base and are limited in range (they are positive integers and can't surpass $2^{32}$). The alphas are non-negative integers (they are not limited in range). The objective is to minimize how many powers the sum has. That is, once the coefficients (alphas) specify how much powers we have in total, we want to minimize the following sum:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \alpha_i$$

Given **n**, the challenge is to solve the problem without relying on some brute-force technique.

Crossposted at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335198/way-to-express-a-number-in-its-most-compact-sum-of-powers#

Comment: Hi. It is possible your representation is the best but if true it is not at all evident.

Comment: Hi! I agree, Piquito. That's why I said "there is at least one that requires only two betas". It's possible that there are more representations that require only two betas, or one that only requires one beta. But I came up with that example just to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to verify whether some number is the sum of two powers with base limited to $2^{32}$ and exponent $1$ allowed ?

Comment: Hello DaviFN. One thing is to say that $N$ is equal to two power sums because I wrote it that way but very differently, another thing is to answer when $N$ is such a sum. The latter is very difficult. Cheers.

Comment: You might want to add an integer restriction. (My calculator can calculate a single beta of our choice, if we allow non-integer powers :)

Comment: Peter understood it correctly. Besides verify, I want yo know what is such a sum that has the less betas (i.e. less terms) possible. And yes, I forgot to mention betas are integers. Exponent one is allowed. Piquito, you're right; there might not be a representation for n. I'll reformulate the problem in order to allow any n to be represented.

Comment: Please confirm that the exponent of $\beta_i$ is constrained to be $i$.

Comment: Yes, Yves Daoust. It is.

Comment: @DaviFN: in practice, as coefficients can be zero, that means that the powers must be increasing. And as the bases can be taken in any order, means that the powers must be distinct. Can some of the $\beta$s be equal ?

Comment: The value of the betas are arbitary; they may be the same (the only restriction is that they are non-negative integers). The objective is, given n, find the values for the parameters alphas and betas such that the sum of the alphas are the minimum possible.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't make sense for any beta to be zero. Betas are positive integers. (obs: if alpha at i is zero, there is no need to specify beta at i)

Comment: Adam P. Goucher pointed out an important thing on the cross-post of this question at MathOverflow; the way the question is formulated prevents reusing exponents. That wasn't what I meant to express. I'll once again reformulate the question. Sorry, Yves Daoust, I suppose that's why you asked.

Comment: I now realize I didn't realize Peter hadn't understand it correctly and I confirmed he has understood it correctly. Sorry. Peter; not only two powers; as many powers as necessary, but the sum of the coefficients (i.e. the alphas) must be the smallest possible.

Comment: Please try to wait at least a week or so before you cross-post to another site, and then provide a link when you do. You asked basically the same question just a couple of hours ago at MathOverflow at [Way to express a number in its most compact sum of powers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335198/way-to-express-a-number-in-its-most-compact-sum-of-powers).

Comment: First treat large $n$: The largest coprime powers in your allowed range are $M_1=\beta_1^{\gamma_1}=(2^{32})^{2^{32}}$ and $M_2=\beta_2^{\gamma_2}=(2^{32}-1)^{2^{32}}$. All sufficiently big $n$ can be written as $n=\alpha_1 M_1+\alpha_2 M_2$ with $\alpha_1\ge 0$ and $0\le \alpha_2<M_1$. So for such large $n$, we have $(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)M_1=n+(M_1-M_2)\alpha_2$ , so $\alpha_1+\alpha_2$ somewhere between $\frac n{M_1}$ and $\frac n{M_1}+M_1-M_2$. Thus with this methos asymptotically $\alpha_1+\alpha_2=\frac n{M_1}+O(1)$ and $\frac n{M_1}$ is clearly unbeatable.